# Moneris - Setting up a Test Hosting Pay Page

Tags: payment

I'm trying to make a fix to a moneris website, but I have to change the mode of moneris to test to test the changes before pushing in production.

I'm trying the code on the example page as is and got an error. "Invalid store credentials."

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION= https://esqa.moneris.com/HPPDP/index.php >
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="ps_store_id" VALUE="AF4Fs1024">
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="hpp_key" VALUE="Hsjh4GSr4g">
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="charge_total" VALUE="1.00">
    <!--MORE OPTIONAL VARIABLES CAN BE DEFINED HERE -->
    <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="SUBMIT" VALUE="Click to proceed to Secure Page">
</FORM>
```

So if this is not how you can make a test payment to test the process, how can you?

PS: Seems there's no moneris tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to goto the developers page of Moneris and create a test environment first [Developer Page](https://esqa.moneris.com/)

After creating the test store you'll need to input the store id and hp key in the values of the form you posted.